# Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

gives: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun`
but I've set `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` in `/etc/environment`

```
source /etc/environment
```

gives the path I've set i.e `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`

The next time I try `echo $JAVA_HOME`, the wrong path is displayed.

Comment: Don't user-specific settings override the environment variables? Did you set anything in your .bashrc (or what the file is called in Ubuntu)?

Comment: There is also an AskUbuntu site where you can find better answers than here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/121654/how-to-set-default-java-version

Comment: I've checked and there is no JAVA_HOMEpath set in .bashrc and profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably code in `/etc/profile` or `~/.bashrc` which sets the variable again.

Try `grep -r JAVA_HOME /etc` and `grep JAVA_HOME ~/.??*` to find places where it's used.

To avoid trouble like this, I usually create shell scripts in `~/bin/` which have the same name as the tool that I want to execute which prepare the environment.

Comment: When I tried grep -r JAVA_HOME /etc, it gave /etc/bash.bashrc~:JAVA_HOME = /usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_31.But when I looked at bash.bashrc manually I did not see JAVA_HOME.

Comment: The `~` at the end of the file means it's a backup. So you have two files. You looked at the one which isn't active.

Comment: grep JAVA_HOME ~/.??* helped. The path of JAVA_HOME was overridden in .bashrc in my /home/biplov/.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu the recommended way seems to be to add the line `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` to `/etc/environment` and use the update-alternatives tool to manage the actual jvm.

You may have a script in `/etc/profile.d/` overriding this which should be removed.

You can see which java alternatives are currently installed and available by running:

```
update-java-alternatives --list
```

To choose a jvm to use, run the following command with whatever version suits you:

```
update-java-alternatives --set java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
```